# Knowing to what degree delta should be in limit definition of multivariable functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that by limit definition,
$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$
such that

If $0<||P-A||<\delta$ then $|f(P)-L|<\epsilon$

Now I am answering a question such as

**Prove, by definition, that
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)} (3x^2+xy-2y^2)=0$**.

The problem is I can't get a wrap around to how much will I increase $\delta$ to find it suitable for $\epsilon$. I get stuck at ${(x-2)}^2+{(y-3)}^2<\delta^2$ and I can't make it to become $(3x^2+xy-2y^2)$.

**How should I easily know when should I stop increasing the value of $\delta$ to find an $\epsilon>f(P)$?**

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $3x^2+xy-2y^2=(x+y)(3x-2y)=(x-2+y-3+5)(3(x-2)-2(y-3))$.

Comment: I see now. But what I want to know is some techniques of how to find the epsilon equal delta in a very fast and efficient way.